# jQuery :not() selector for class not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following HTML:

```
<ul> 
    <li>Hello</li>      
    <li>World</li>
    <li class="not_me">Hi</li>
</ul>
```

And I'd like to get all texts inside the list items as an array in one jQuery call:

```
arr = $('li:not(.not_me)').map(function(el, i) {
    return $(el).text();
});
```

Expected result:

> > arr = ['Hello', 'World']

Actual result:

> > arr = ['Hello', 'World', 'Hi']

Why is my :not() exclusion not working? Writing it with quotes "not('.not_me')" gives the same result.

Here's a JSFiddle showing the problem: **http://jsfiddle.net/cC8fT/683/**

Comment: I believe your code actually does work, you're just testing it incorrectly.

Comment: 1) currently, `el` is the index and `i` is the element. 2) it work : http://jsfiddle.net/wMv9e/

Comment: The array you're printing is not the result of that expression.

Comment: How should my jQuery look like to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:not` operator is working just fine, but there are some other issues in the code.

You have swapped the `el` and `i` parameters, so the element comes in the `i` parameter and the index comes in the `el` parameter.

The result is not an array, it's a jQuery object that contains the array. You would use the `get` method to get the array out of the object.

```
var arr = $('li:not(.not_me)').map(function(i, el) {
  return $(el).text();
}).get();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/P8uS6/

Comment: Actually according to [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) you are supposed to have it `el` then `i`

Comment: @No1_Melman: You are looking at the documentation for the wrong method. Here is the correct one: http://api.jquery.com/map/

Comment: i did just look at that documentation, and as it says I am wrong.

Comment: Tried this jsfiddle today (november 17, 2016), and it doesn't work. It shows "Hello", "World" and "Hi". Is this a jQuery bug that got introduced later? I ran into this in my own project, hence my visit to this page.

Answer (score 2):

This works [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cC8fT/687/)

```
arr = $.each($('li:not(.not_me)'), function(i, el) {
    return el;
});
```

The selector `$('li:not(.not_me)')` gives you the array, and the `$.each()` then iterates through everything. In the example you can see a new element block with the new elements.

There are many things you can do, for example if you want just the names you can do this:

```
var arr = [];
$.each($('li:not(.not_me)'), function(i, el) {
   arr.push($(el).val()); // or text
});
```

Sometimes you have to accept you can't and shouldn't do things in one line :). Either it complicates it too much, or makes your code just unreadable.

***EDIT***

Just found that for `$.each` the iterator function needs to have the arguments `index` then `element` rather than the other way

Comment: Thanks, it's a working solution - upvoted. Yet, the second one was what I was actually looking for. It's simply a bit shorter :-)

Comment: Yeah, no worries, it's always good to have a couple of different answer because it allows you to make an informed decision. :)